# It is possible to add mlflow experiences notes using code instead of mlflow UI?

Tags: mlflow

I want to add text to experiences notes without using the mlflow ui
[mlflow UI notes example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WPKN.png)

I can't find that method in the docs https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

To set notes for experiment use:

```
MlflowClient().set_experiment_tag(experiment_id, 
     "mlflow.note.content","<my_note_here>")
```

To set notes for runs use:

```
MlflowClient().set_tag(run_id, 
     "mlflow.note.content","<my_note_here>")
```

[[image: Experiment Note[1]]

[image: LOCAL_REGISTRY Run Note]

Comment: the run note worked, but the experiment note didn't. I am having this issue
"""
mlflow.set_experiment_tag("mlflow.note.content", "hello world")
AttributeError: module 'mlflow' has no attribute 'set_experiment_tag'
"""

Comment: I'm using mlflow 1.7 on the local host. https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tracking.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.set_experiment_tag

Note that this is method not on mlflow but MlflowClient
Here is the example code: https://github.com/dmatrix/tutorials/blob/master/mlflow/labs/00_get_started.py